# Самый первый "Hello world" на C++

Tags: c++, c++builder

Здравствуйте.

Недавно решился взяться за изучение C++, скачал C++ builder XE, открыл книжку-самоучитель по программированию, вроде бы правильно написал самую первую программу (которая с текстом Hello world), она компилируется, но текст не выводится. Потом стало ясно, что надо вроде другую версию C++ или другой компилятор. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как что правильно открывать и что делать. Если это есть где-то в интернете, то буду благодарен за ссылку на материал.

Заранее спасибо!

**Добавлено из комментария**.

Выводится пустая форма. Сейчас я удалил c++ builder xe и поставил c++ builder 6 - результат тот же.

```
// Моя первая программа!

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello world!!!\n";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: давайте для начнём с того, что посмотрим на Ваш код. скорее всего именно там ошибка.

Answer (score 10):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
cout << "Hello world!!!\n";
return 0;
}
```

Пиши так. Думаю так легче. Незачем использовать библиотеку <conio.h> и <_getch>

Comment: Поддерживаю. Если уж изучать C++, то изучать C++, а не всякие расширения компиляторов типа семантики #pragma, нестандартные библиотеки и прочий левак.

А то, бывает, приходят студенты на первый курс, бьют себя пяткой в грудь, мол, знаю я ваши C и C++ чуть не с рождения. А сами "Hello world" начинают с `#include<dos.h>` или собрать программу не могут, работая в терминальном сеансе.

Comment: Глубоко убежден, что нет ничего лучше для изучения С и С++, чем связка Linux+gedit+gcc,

Comment: @mikillskegg с постепенным переходом на Linux+vim+make+gcc

Comment: Или emacs.

Comment: А что вообще можно сделать без conio.h? С какого перепоя такая важная библиотека отсутствует в стандарте? Как человеку увидеть результаты работы его программы, чтобы это не выглядело криво (если, например, заменить getch() на scanf())?

Answer (score 6):

1. Скачиваете, устанавливаете и запускаете [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express).
2. Создаете проект: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, выбираете тип - консольное приложение Win32 и имя - helloworld.
3. Редактируете строки в файл helloworld.cpp.

- 

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь жмете <kbd>F5</kbd> и наслаждаетесь результатом. :)

Comment: Вот то, что надо было! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Ну и зачем человеку, пишущему helloworld знать что такое tmain и stdafx. А потом он все программы будет начинать с подключения stdafx и спрашивать почему не компилируется.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь писать этот код, находясь в проекте оконного приложения. Ваша функция main никогда не выполняется, потому что выполнение программы начинается с вызова WinMain. Создайте, не сохраняя проект, создаваемый по умолчанию, проект консольного приложения (File-> New Project -> Console Wizard, вроде бы в шестёрке оно так), и увидите уже сгенерированную функцию main. Впишите в неё код и будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score -3):

В шестом билдере надо вопервых подключить библиотеку `#include <conio.h>`. Во вторых - вместо `return 0;` написать `getch ();` Это функция которая содержится в вышеуказанной библиотеке и она не закрывает программу, пока не нажать любую клавишу.

```
#include <conio.h>
```

вместо ретурн в конце:

```
getch();
```

Comment: Вместо того чтобы публиковать ещё один ответ, редактируйте этот с помощью кнопки [edit]. Если она недоступна - зарегистрируйтесь на сайте.

Comment: Для форматирования текста используйте разметку markdown: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help